# overload += in python for a mapping type

Tags: python, dictionary, operator-overloading

I'd like to use a += notation for updating a dict-like object in Python. I want to have the same behavior as dict.update method. Here is my class (dictionary with "." access):

```
class sdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr, None)
    __setattr__= dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__= dict.__delitem__
```

I tried:

```
__iadd__ = dict.update
```

And:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.update(other)
    return self
```

but none of these work. (the first destroys the original dictionary and the second generates SyntaxError)

Update:
Second definition actually works. It didn't work for me because I forgot `def`. The first one doesn't work because dict.update returns None.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think all you're missing is a def:

```
class sdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr, None)
    __setattr__= dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__= dict.__delitem__
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.update(other)
        return self

>>> a = sdict()
>>> a.b = 3
>>> a
{'b': 3}
>>> a.b
3
>>> a['b']
3
>>> a += {'fred': 3}
>>> a
{'b': 3, 'fred': 3}
```

Comment: Augh, beat me to it! Here, have my valuable +1

Comment: Oops... That was stupid... Thank you for the answer! Any idea of why `__iadd__ = dict.update` doesn't work?

Comment: @user1084871: It breaks the requirement of [`__iadd__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) that it returns the result of the assignment.